# Node and Express with MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, connection

I have the following problem. I have access data from a database that I use both in the script (Node) and in the Workbench / DBeaver. The two third-party applications work correctly, I can access the database, make changes, delete, create, all normally, but when I try to login through my script to be able to have this web-level maneuverability through Node, the error "TIMEOUT" appears.

The question is, already use Knex.js, mysql, @ mysql / xdevapi and the three accuse the same thing. The problem is that when it comes to this type of problem, it doesn't mention what error it is, it simply gives a timeout, be it a password error, login and etc., so I can't identify what the real problem is.

- The doors are released 22, 3306, 33060.
- The login and password are the same used in other software.
- The Firewall and any protection that exists is released from access, so if the login and password match, I would be free to access normally.

I'm just trying to show you when you connect to the bank or not using this code:

````
        if(err){
          console.log(' | Error to connect on database! Reason:', err.code);
          return;
        }
        console.log(' | Connection established');
      });```


The results is  | Error to connect on database! Reason: ETIMEDOUT
````

Comment: there is no simple way to handle this, i think that yur app can't reach the server, that can have a lot of reason, i use usually wireshark t see what happens at network level, you didn#t show enough to see if your app is local access or remote

Comment: My application is running on local access, obtaining information from the remote database, I have already tested this in another application and it works normally, the question is that there is another configuration. Later, I will put this application on a server so that it can work remotely too.

Comment: i am still somwhat confused, you test with this account and another appilcation and it works? if they have thesame configuration it should work, if yu have different users, you have to grant the same rights